# Error en envió de correos por formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp, email

Realizo una prueba simple de enviar un correo por medio de un formulario PHP, pero sale el mensaje que se envio, reviso mi correo y no me llaga nada.
Realizo la prueba en Mercury que esta incluido en XAMPP y sin problema alguno envía correos, pero desde mi formulario PHP no me llega nada a pesar de que me sale el mensaje de enviado.
Ya se configuro Mercury para el envió de correos de forma local.

#### Archivo php

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['asunto']) && !empty ($_POST['asunto']) &&
  isset($_POST['desde']) && !empty ($_POST['desde']) &&
  isset($_POST['mensaje']) && !empty ($_POST['asunto']))
  {
   $destinatario = "carlos.pruebas@gmail.com";
   $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
   $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
   $desde = "From:" . $_POST['desde'];
   
  mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $desde); 
   
   echo "correo enviado";
   
  }else{
   echo "correo no enviado";
     
  }
   
   
  
?>
```

#### Formulario

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Correo </title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form action="enviar_c.php" method="post">
 <table width="200" height="200" border="0">
 
 <tr>
 <td>Asunto:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="asunto"></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
 <td>Desde:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="desde"></td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
 <td>Mensaje:</td>
 <td><textarea type="text" name="mensaje"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
 <td></td>
 
 

 <input type="submit" value="enviar correo" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Podrias adjuntar en tu pregunta el mensaje de error que obtienes?

Comment: No veo en ningun lado del codigo que has colocado dicha sentencia `if`. Creo que seria importante ara cualquier persona que intente responder la pregunta =)

Comment: $mail no existe, creo que por ahi van tus problemas

Comment: Podrías revisar el error.log de `apache` o del servidor que utilices.

Comment: Ya modifique ambos archivos ahora ya me sale en mi pagina php que se envio el correo, pero no me llega nada revisando el correo

Comment: Coloca un try catch para conocer el error:
try {
 mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $desde); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getMessage()); exit();
}

Answer (score 2):

No estoy seguro si esta es tu respuesta, pero pude probar tu código y a mi si me funcionó.

```
if (isset($_POST["nombre"]) && !empty($_POST["nombre"])
    && isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])
    && isset($_POST["telefono"]) && !empty($_POST["telefono"])
    && isset($_POST["mensaje"]) && !empty($_POST["mensaje"]) ){

    $destino = "personadestino@gmail.com";
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\nCorreo:" .$correo . 
                    "\nTelefono: " . $telefono . "\nmensaje" . $mensaje;
    $from = "Persona";
    mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido, $from);
    echo"Mensaje  enviado con exito"; 
}else {
    echo"Error de envio";
}

header("Location:salir.html")
```

Comment: tome tu codigo y lo modifique y de igual forma me sale el mensaje que se envio correctante el correo.... mi pregunta es configuraste Mercury para que funcionara o que hiciste?

Comment: Gracias, es primera vez que respondo en un foro como este. Bueno lo que hice es utilizar su código y modificar algunas partes, luego lo subí a  un servidor.

Answer (score 1):

La funcion mail devuelve un valor booleano. Sera true si se "acepta" para envio, o false si no se acepta. Asi que podrias añadir un check primero obteniendo ese valor y analizarlo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['asunto']) && !empty ($_POST['asunto']) &&
  isset($_POST['desde']) && !empty ($_POST['desde']) &&
  isset($_POST['mensaje']) && !empty ($_POST['asunto']))
  {
      $destinatario = "carlos.pruebas@gmail.com";
      $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
      $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
      $desde = "From:" . $_POST['desde'];

     $result = mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $desde); 

      if($result == true)
          echo "correo enviado";
      else
          echo "correo no enviado";
  }else{
      echo "correo no enviado";

  }

?>
```

Pero el hecho de "aceptar" el envio, no **asegura** que llegue el correo al destino. Revisa la documentacion de esa funcion:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:



`if(isset($_POST['asunto']) && isset($_POST['desde']) && isset($_POST['mensaje']))
  {
      $destinatario = "carlos.pruebas@gmail.com";
      $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
      $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
      $desde = "From:" . $_POST['desde'];

  if(mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $desde))
  {
      echo "correo enviado";
  }
  else
  {
      echo "correo no enviado";
  }


}else{
      echo "correo no enviado";
      // deberías poner algo como "Los campos no deben estar vacíos"

}

?>`

Si no resulta quita la parte de:  $desde = "From:" . $_POST['desde']; ademas de la variable $desde en la condición if(mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $desde))